# sublime yes_no_cancel_dialog leaves mouse cursor on drag mode upon close

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to show a dialog popup in my plugin when the view loses input focus with ***sublime_plugin.EventListener*** on ***on_deactivate*** method. I used ***sublime.yes_no_cancel_dialog*** which returns sublime.DialogResult as 0,1 or 2.

```py
class myEventListeners(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_deactivated(self, view):
        if sublime.yes_no_cancel_dialog("Do you want to save this?") == sublime.DIALOG_YES:
            print("YES")
```

The problem I'm facing is, that when the dialog box popups and the user clicks one of the options, the sublime window loses focus on the window's view. The mouse cursor drags the file that has the active view.

So when I switched from my currently open file to the *test.py* file in sublime window, I get the popup and after clicking Yes, the mouse cursor has the *test.py* file in drag mode instead of normal insert mode where I can simply write new texts in *test.py*. A screenshot is attached for the drag behavior.[image]

I have to drag this *test.py* view to the scroll tabs (grey area on the screenshot) at the top (just below the Menu bar) before I can edit this file.

Also, got the same behavior with ***sublime.ok_cancel_dialog*** popup.

Sublime Build: **Build 4126**

Platform: **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**

Comment: What build of Sublime are you using (**`Help → About Sublime Text`**) and what platform are you on?

Comment: I'm using Build 4126 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Thanks.

Comment: I've tested this code on Win10, macOS Catalina, and Ubuntu 22.04 (Intel all), all using the latest dev build, 4134. It doesn't always give this same exact behavior, but on all three platforms it does wonky things with the other open tabs. I'd say this is definitely a bug. A quick search of the [issues](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues) didn't reveal anything similar, so please [open a new bug report](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/new/choose) and add as much detail as possible. Please also reference this question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the same behaviour if you use `on_deactivated_async` instead?

Comment: yes, the same behavior with the on_deactivated_asyn. @OdatNurd